# VideoPlayer widget keeps on giving NullPointerException of invoking a virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-videoview

Right now I am trying to play the video in the start of my App as welcome greetings I followed this [Video player link](https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-advanced-course-practicals/unit-5-advanced-graphics-and-views/lesson-13-media/13-1-p-playing-video-with-videoview/13-1-p-playing-video-with-videoview.html#alreadyknow)  before adding the controller. I wrote the following code and it ran successfully in a separate `Activity`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String VIDEO_SAMPLE = "tacoma_narrows";
private VideoView mVideoView;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    initializePlayer();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    releasePlayer();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        mVideoView.pause();
    }
}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mVideoView = findViewById(R.id.startingvideo);


}

private Uri getMedia(String mediaName) {
    return Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +
            "/raw/" + mediaName);
}
private void initializePlayer() {
    Uri videoUri = getMedia(VIDEO_SAMPLE);
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
    mVideoView.start();
}
private void releasePlayer() {
    mVideoView.stopPlayback();
}}
```

but when I tried to add the same code in my welcome screen then I got the following message

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{sterlingtechsolutionpk.buttonbutton/sterlingtechsolutionpk.buttonbutton.Welcome_Screen}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(android.net.Uri)' on a null
>   object reference

The .xml file is

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/loading_screen"
android:minHeight="177dp"
tools:context="sterlingtechsolutionpk.buttonbutton.Welcome_Screen">

<!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
     is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
     TextureView, etc. -->

<!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
     android:fitsSystemWindows. -->

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/start_progres"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"

    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="362dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:progressBackgroundTint="#fff200"
    android:progressTint="#005cef"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.455" />
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/startingvideo"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="4:3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

Any Help regarding this is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Are you sure `activity_main` is the xml you have posted ? I guess  You probably messes up with using wrong xml file . if yes then its should work with the above code . Try clean build and re install .

Comment: Read the Exception message. The issue is in `Welcome_Screen`, not `MainActivity`, which is what you've posted.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are using the wrong `id`?

Code:

`mVideoView = findViewById(R.id.videoview);`

Layout:

`android:id="@+id/startingvideo"`

You should change one of these lines so that they are matching.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using wrong ids for your `mVideoView`. It returns a `NullPointerException` because `mVideoView` is `null`, like you give wrong `id`.
   change it to :

   `mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.startingvideo);`
2. try calling  `initializePlayer()` from `onCreate()` instead of `onStart()`;
3. check if `videoUri` is not `null`. Your `getMedia` method is maybe returning a `null` value.

Comment: I have corrected the ids and changed the code as you suggested but no benifit

Comment: Also this code runs perfectly in a seperate activity. . . but here after correctig the ids thing it is not working

Comment: Can you post your VideoView class please?

Comment: `try calling initializePlayer() from onCreate() instead of onStart()`? This does not make any sense . `onStart()` is called after `onCreate()`.

Comment: Yes I know, but we don't know about his VideoView class, and like he said it works on another activity and not in this one. The only thing wrong in his code was mVideoView ids. That is why I asked for his VideoView class.